# Java - 2D Array - Cannot use enhanced loop?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, 2d

```
    public static int berekenSomElementenIdentiekRijKolom(int[][] a) {
        int som = 0;
//        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
//            for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
//                if ( i == j ) {
//                    som += a[i][j];
//                }               
//            }
//
//        }
//        return som;
//    }

    for (int[] rij : a){
        for (int[] kol :a){
            if (rij == kol){
                som+= int[rij][kol];
            }
        }

    } 
    return som;
}
```

So here's the code that im working on.
The goal is simple if row index equals column index sum it up. The normal loop works but i am having trouble converting this to an enhanced loop.
Ive heard that it just sometimes doesnt work and il accept it.

Comment: You can't. There's no index in an enhanced for loop. Unless you want to increment a variable in parallel, but that's pretty pointless.

Comment: To me the commented code is so much easier to read

Comment: @shmosel do you mind showing an example for educational purposes ? and thanks for the fast answer!

Comment: Your code is equivalent to `for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { som += a[i][i]; }`, why even have a second loop?

Comment: if ( i == j ) @ElliottFrisch - meaning if the index of row and column is same we sum it up

Comment: @Daxious Which means the `if` is only entered when `i` and `j` are the same value. And they are **both** constrained to the range `0` to `a.length`; so when will `i == j`? Same as in my much more efficient version.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch holy shit that makes much more sense. hahah something clicked in my head, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to get an index in an enhanced-for loop. You would have to track the position yourself:

```
int i = 0;
for (int[] rij : a) {
    int j = 0;
    for (int kol : rij) {
        if (i == j) {
            som += kol;
        }
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

I think it's clear that the original way is preferable.

But there's really no reason to iterate over the entire matrix in the first place. Here's an even simpler solution:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (i < a[i].length) {
        som += a[i][i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Im having such a hard time trying to comprehend this since you posted this. Especially the if part, never seen array[index].length , care to explain just a little?

Comment: That's just getting the length of the inner array. If the array is 5x3, for example, you'll get an out of bounds error if you try to index (4, 4).